# MVC via Symfony

Tags: symfony

There is a project in Symfony, who want to remake using MVC. The project has controllers and twig patterns , it is only necessary to fasten model.**In which Symfony project directory to properly create model files ? Is there anything in Symfony tool allows to do it , rather than just to create these files and to connect them to the controller ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Symfony standard edition as your starting point. If you try to make something own without prior experience with code organization in Symfony you will make it only worse.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard

Standard edition above 2.8 version is pretty slim and doesn't force you to use everything if you don't need to.

If you need only "Model" classes then create them in `src/AppBundle/Model` and if you need Entities that will be persisted in database put them in `src/AppBundle/Entity`. Read about generation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html I will help you started

Comment: I can't found 'Model' folder here. There are controllers and views, but I need models too.

Comment: if you need only "Model" classes then create them in ```src/AppBundle/Model``` and if you need Entities that will be persisted in database put them in ```src/AppBundle/Entity```. Read about generation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html I will help you started